# Accord du participe passé avec un pronom relatif

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé

J'ai du mal à savoir laquelle de ces deux versions est juste et pourquoi :

1. les choses auxquelles il est confronté.
2. les choses auxquelles il est confrontées.

L'accord est-il nécessaire avec les objets référencés par un pronom relatif comme dans « La voiture que j'ai conduite » ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

En règle générale, l'accord avec participe passé se fait selon l'auxiliaire utilisé.

Si le participe passé est employé sans auxiliaire, il s'emploie comme un adjectif qualitatif, c'est-à-dire qu'il s'accorde avec le sujet qu'il décrit.

> Les jours passés ne reviennent pas.

Si l'auxiliaire est le verbe *être* (comme dans ce cas-ci), le participe s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le sujet du verbe.

> Les choses auxquelles il est confronté.

Si l'auxiliaire est le verbe *avoir*, le participe passé s'accorde avec le complément d'objet direct, **si celui-ci est placé avant le verbe**. S'il n'y a pas de complément d'objet direct (COD) ou s'il est placé après le verbe, il ne s'accorde pas.

> Les lettres qu'il a écrites. *(COD avant le verbe)*
>   Il a écrit les lettres. *(COD après le verbe)*
>   Elles ont écrit. *(Pas de COD)*

Il existe d'autres cas particuliers qui sont décrits en détail sur le site de la [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=199&niveau=) de l'Office québécois de la langue française.

Comment: Précision : si l'auxiliaire est le verbe _être_ ou un verbe d'état (_sembler_, _paraître_, etc), le participe s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le sujet du verbe.

Comment: merci, je comprends mieux maintenant:)

Answer (score 6):

On accorde un participe passé utilisé comme adjectif avec le nom qu'il qualifie :

> La voiture réparé**e** a été repeinte en rouge.
>
> La voiture est réparé**e**.

Pour un verbe conjugué avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*, on accorde le participe passé avec son COD quand celui-ci est placé avant :

> La voiture que j'ai réparé**e** hier est comme neuve.
>
> Quelles voitures avez-vous réparé**es** ?

mais pas lorsqu'il se situe après :

> J'ai répar**é** la voiture rapidement.

Il faut parfois faire attention aux pièges :

> La voiture que j'ai voul**u** réparer était trop abîmée.

*La voiture* est COD de *réparer*, et le COD de *vouloir* est la proposition « *réparer (la voiture)* » ; il n'y a donc pas d'accord à faire sur *vouloir*.

---

Quelques cas plus compliqués :

- Lorsqu'on utilise des verbes pronominaux, l'auxiliaire *être* remplace l'auxiliaire *avoir*, mais l'accord se fait aussi avec le COD placé avant :

  > Les voitures se sont percuté**es**.
  >
  > Les voitures qu'elles se sont offert**es**.

  On ne l'accorde pas lorsqu'il se situe après :

  > Elles se sont offer**t** des voitures.

Et des cas « subtils »…

- Il y a des cas tordus :

  > Les mécaniciens se sont vu**s** réparer la voiture en un rien de temps.
  >
  > La voiture s'est v**u** réparer en un rien de temps.

  La première phrase est fondée sur la construction *voir ‘qqun’ ‘faire qqch’*. Les mécaniciens ont vu *eux-mêmes*. Par contre, dans la deuxième phrase, la voiture a vu *qu'on la réparait*, c'est l'infinitif qui est COD de *voir*, comme dans « on a vu construire cette maison ».
- Autre cas, récurrent et peu évident :

  > La voiture s'est fai**t** réparer en un rien de temps.

  qui peut signifier « la voiture a fait *réparer elle-même* », ou plutôt dans ce cas précis « on a fait *réparer la voiture* ». Pas d'accord, car le complément est l'action.
- …

Comment: Quand le COD est un infinitif + ..., pourquoi n'y a-t-il pas la concordance du pronom ? Par exemple, **Nous avons vu démolir la vielle prison --> Nous l'avons vu démolir.** Mais on parle encore de la vielle prison, qui est un nom féminin.

Comment: @LaPrevoyance : les pronoms objets sont *le* et *la*, mais lorsqu'ils sont élidés ils deviennent tous les deux *l'*, on ne peut plus les distinguer.

Answer (score 3):

Pas d'accord avec [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1979)

Dans les deux cas, « Ces pommes » ou « Les pommes » sont compléments de l'infinitif, pas du participe passé. Donc on n'accorde dans aucun cas.

Par contre, la question aurait pu se poser dans les cas suivants :

- La pianiste que j'ai **entendue** jouer (J'ai entendu (qui ?) la pianiste jouer (quoi ?) (on ne sait pas))
- La symphonie que j'ai **entendu** jouer (J'ai entendu (qui ?) (on ne sait pas) jouer (quoi ?) la symphonie)

(À lire : [accord du participe passe avec un infinitif](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_1_09_accord_du_partisipe_passe_avec_un_infinitif.shtml) )

Les règles complètes de l'accord du participe passé sont longues, complexes et comportent beaucoup d'exceptions. Rien ne remplace une bonne grammaire. À noter que le logiciel Antidote (payant) propose des articles clairs et relativement complets sur le sujet.

Comment: ça ne choque que moi que le lien parlant des accords du participe passé aille sur une page nommée **partisipe**, ils ont perdu leur Bescherelle chez reverso ??

Comment: Ah, je n'avais pas vu l'URL, en effet. Pour l'anecdote, le formulaire de connexion à la version en ligne du Bon Usage de Grevisse a longtemps utilisé l'orthographe « connection ». Comme quoi les webmasters ne sont pas toujours calés dans le domaine qu'ils hébergent. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Le participe passé conjugué avec l'auxiliaire *avoir* s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le complément d'objet direct, si celui-ci est placé avant :

- Les lettres reçues.
- La rumeur répandue.

Si le complément d'objet direct est placé après ou s'il n'existe pas, le participe passé conjugué avec *avoir* reste invariable :

- Nos enquêtes ont échoué.
- J'ai reçu des lettres.

Bien évidemment il existe de nombreux cas particuliers lorsque le participe est suivi d’un infinitif ou précédé de « en ».

Vous pouvez en savoir plus en lisant l'article de Wikipedia à propos de l'[Accord du participe passé en français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_du_participe_pass%C3%A9_en_fran%C3%A7ais#R.C3.A8gle_g.C3.A9n.C3.A9rale).

Comment: Ça ne répond pas précisément à la question : est-ce aussi valable si le complément d'objet suivi de *que*.

Comment: Les deux premiers exemples illustrent des emplois adjectivaux où l'accord est systématique (et les noms *lettres* et *rumeur* ne sont pas complément d'objet puisqu'il n'y a pas de verbe)

Answer (score -2):

On accorde le participe passé après un *que* s'il se rapporte au sujet de la phrase **et** lorsque le groupe nominal est placé avant le verbe au participe passé. Ainsi :

1. Ces pommes que j'ai voulues acheter
2. Les pommes que j'ai voulu acheter

Le cas 1. : le sujet de la phrase est "ces pommes" et le participe passé qui leur est relatif est accordé. Dans le cas 2., le sujet de la phrase est "je" et non pas "ces pommes", donc on ne l'accorde pas.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah je comprends, merci! Cela m'aide beaucoup :)

Comment: Ninefingers: cette réponse est incorrecte et en plus n'a pas vraiment de sens. Le seul sujet qu'il y a dans ces phrases nominales se trouve dans la subordonnée et c'est *je*. Le complément d'objet direct de *vouloir* est ici l'infinitif *acheter*, et il n'y a donc pas d'accord à faire.