# Doit-on ajouter un « e » féminin la fin du participe passé ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, accord, passé-composé

Quand doit-on ajouter un `e` féminin à la fin des verbes au passé composé ?

Par exemple, est-ce que « Elle m'a vue il y a 2h. » est correct ?

J'aimerais savoir ce qui détermine la conjugaison du verbe (le sujet ou l'objet, dans cet exemple "elle" ou "me" ?).

Comment: Voir réponse de Karen ici : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/accord-du-participe-passe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avec l’auxiliaire avoir, l’accord se fait avec le complément d’objet direct *si celui-ci est placé devant le verbe*.

La phrase « Elle m’a vue il y a deux heures » est donc correcte, si le narrateur est une narratrice.