# Participe passé plural

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

With reference to the participe passé here, are these sentences correct?

> les règles que la société avait défini
>
> les comportements qui sont admissible selon les règles qu'on a défini

It was my thinking that they should be *definies*.

A person adept in French told me that it should be défini and referenced this link to explain why:

http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-employe-avec-l-auxiliaire-avoir-179.php

Can someone tell me which is correct and explain why?

Comment: This question has been answered before, e.g. [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/accord-du-participe-pass%C3%A9-avec-un-pronom-relatif) and [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/doit-on-ajouter-un-e-f%C3%A9minin-la-fin-du-participe-pass%C3%A9?rq=1).

Comment: Probably but it was still necessary to ask this with regard to this exact sentence since that person had told me it was certainly the case, but it seems I was right all along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about how the French adept came to that conclusion but according to the linked page, the agreement is expected:

> *les règles que la société avait défini**es***

and

> *les comportements qui sont admissible**s** selon les règles qu[**e l**]'on a défini**es***

Comment: Ok thankyou. Can you explain why? It is because règles is feminine ?

Comment: *règles* is feminine plural and most relevantly, it is a direct object that precedes the participe passé. That situation is what triggers agreement of the participe passé.

Comment: Ok that's great, thanks very much for your help.