# Quelqu'un les a forcément mises quelque part

Tags: verbes

everyone! I'm learning French on my own during my leisure time. I occasionally watch Peppa pig in French.

In one episode, papa pig could not find his glasses and, referring to his glasses, he said "Quelqu'un les a forcément mises quelque part". I am very confused by the word "mises" used here. Why isn't the present perfect form of mettre "mis" used here?

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

There is no present perfect in French. The verb is *mettre* used at the *passé composé*.

The *passé composé* is built with an auxiliary verb conjugated at the present and a *participe passé*.

Because the auxiliary verb here is *avoir*, the rule is to have the past participle to agree if the COD (*complément d'objet direct*) is located before it. That is the case here: *les* is a pronoun referring to *les lunettes*. The word  *lunettes* is both feminine and plural thus the past participle is *mis**es***.

If the COD is located after the past-participle, the is no agreement, compare:

> *...a **mis** les lunettes...*

and

> *...les a **mises**...*

See [Accord du participe passé avec un pronom relatif](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/accord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-avec-un-pronom-relatif)

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is true, but if you want more details: This sentence is equivalent to: **Quelqu'un a forcément mis *les lunettes* quelque part**. Les lunettes in this case is a *complément d'objet direct* and *féminin*. In your sentence, **les** is replacing **lunettes** so **les** is a *complément d'objet direct*. Since verb *mettre* is conjugated with *auxiliaire avoir* in the past, you must do the *accord en genre et en nombre* meaning *masculin et féminin* (male and female) and *singulier et pluriel* (singular and plural).